# First time login to the app with facebook login, will redirect to app register page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent, facebook-login

When a user login first time into my app with facebook login button,
I want it to redirect them to app signup/register activity for FB users ( `key-in username/password` etc), next time they login again with FB,
the app will check the server if the FB user Acc exist? & skip the sign up activity for FB and redirect to the main landing page activity,

my question here is where do I place my code to check DB if the FB user is already registered or not?

is it in the:

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}?
```

I know the intent do return data but have no idea how to access it, since I dont know the name of the extra keys...or is there another way to get it?

I have checked the facebook dev page, but am confused and dont undestand it

I am currently using facebook login button for this

can someone provide me a simple structure of how the code would look like?

UPDATE:
Here is how my `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()` look like:

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        // App code
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                        try {

                            //=================================================================//
                            // Create User Code
                            System.out.println("FB successful login");
                            user = new User();

                            //user.facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                            user.userID = object.getString("id").toString();
                            user.email = object.getString("email").toString();
                            user.name = object.getString("name").toString();
                            user.gender = object.getString("gender").toString();

                            PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(user, MainLoginActivity.this);

                            //STOP, if NOT Registered
                            //Function to check if email exist in DB
                            facebookCheckEmail(user.email);

                            if(fbresponse.equals("ok")) {

                                //=================================================================//
                                // Start MainActivity Code
                                Intent intent=new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                                startActivity(intent);

                                Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "Welcome " + user.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                finish();

                            } else if(fbresponse.equals("no")){

                                //=================================================================//
                                // Pop up Dialog to Register & goto FB Register Activity


                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

                                builder.setTitle("You Have Not Yet Registered");
                                builder.setMessage("You have not yet registered using Facebook, register now?");

                                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        // Goto FB Register Activity

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }

                                });

                                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // Do nothing
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                alert.show();


                            }


                            //=================================================================//
                            // Start MainActivity Code
                            //Intent intent=new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                            //startActivity(intent);

                            //Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "Welcome " + user.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //finish();



                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("FB failed login = " + e.toString());
                        }


                    }

                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields","id,name,email,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Facebook error " + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "Something goes wrong.." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

and `facebookCheckEmail()` function below:

```
private void facebookCheckEmail( String email ) {



    fbCheckEmail_params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    fbCheckEmail_params.put("Email", email);

    final GsonRequest<FbCheckObject> gsonRequest = ApiRequest.gsonFacebookCheckEmailRequest
            (
                    new Response.Listener<FbCheckObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(FbCheckObject fbCheckObject) {


                            try {

                                System.out.println("Status = " + fbCheckObject.getStatus());

                                if (new String(fbCheckObject.getStatus()).equals("ok") == true) {

                                    fbresponse = "ok";

                                } else if(new String(fbCheckObject.getStatus()).equals("no") == true){

                                    fbresponse = "no";

                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                Log.d("Web Service Error", e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // Deal with the error here

                        }
                    },
                    fbCheckEmail_params
            );

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(gsonRequest, TAG);

}
```

the `facebookCheckEmail` is a GSONRequest that takes a `email` parameter and will set a string variable `fbresponse` to the `ok` or `no`, my problem is the value set to `fbresponse` in `facebookCheckEmail()` is not updated and getting `null` when I checked it in `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by using callbackmanager

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.i("NIC", "Success Login");

                        //Call Graph API here to retrieve user's data
                        //Call to you Backend to check if user is registered, then do your stuff here

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(General_login_menu.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("NIC", "Cancel Login");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(General_login_menu.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("NIC", "Error Login");
                    }
                });
```